# access to the path """"" is denied C#

Tags: c#, mysql, backup, mysql-backup

I'm logged in as an admin on my PC, but this shows up

here's my code:

```
string file = "C:\\Users\\owner\\Documents\\backup.sql";
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(constring))
{
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand())
    {
        using (MySqlBackup mb = new MySqlBackup(cmd))
        {
            try
            {
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                mb.ExportToFile(file);
                conn.Close();
            }catch(Exception ex){
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PS: I already have a connection string at the very top of my code.

Comment: is MySqlBackup part of MySql connector? did not saw it never...

Comment: i downloaded it in nuget and it was added on my references

Comment: But it's part of the standard connector or is a package offered by a third party? I ask it because if it's from a third party clarify it to help people trying to help you have all te info needed.

Comment: i downloaded the connector in  mysql's website, and in their packaged i didn't saw mysqlbackup so i downloaded it seperately in the nuget inside the visual studio

Comment: Maybe this is what's happening to you? https://mysqlbackupnet.codeplex.com/workitem/37

Comment: That's because it's a third party package not related to mysql. it's named MySqlBackup .net

Comment: Have you got a stack trace that has more info? I'm assuming the error is at the line `mb.ExportToFile(file);`, but it might be useful to get some more info.

Comment: i cant see mysqlbackup.net on mysql folder, where can i download an installer/connector of it with mysqlbackup.net ?

Comment: here is my stacktrace @Kjartan cant paste it here so here's a link [link]http://scratchpad.io/panicky-digestion-5041

Answer (score 0):

There is a possibility, that you are getting the error because the file doesn't exist. I could be wrong, but I looked into the source and it doesn't check whether the file already exists.

Comment: i'm creating a new file which is the backup of the database.

Answer (score -3):

hey ?  are you using mysqlbackup.dll as reference ? if yes maybe this can help .. just go to the folder you want to be the storage of your saved files

```
Private Sub BackupDatabaseToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BackupDatabaseToolStripMenuItem.Click

  'using mysqlbackup.dll as reference

  Dim cmd As MySqlCommand = New MySqlCommand

  cmd.Connection = connect()

  Dim filepth As String = "C:\Users\IT\Documents\DB_Backup.sql"

  Dim mb As MySqlBackup = New MySqlBackup(cmd)

  mb.ExportToFile(filepth)

  MsgBox("Database Backup Successfully !", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Project")

  disconnect()
End Sub
```

Comment: The question is in C#, your answer seems to be in Visual Basic.